# From within a virtual host how to know the virtual network type?

Tags: networking, powershell, hyper-v

How would you determine the  virtual network type (external or internal)  from an hyper-v virtual host ?
My goal is to activate DHCP for internal network and static ip for external network.
Activating or disabling dhcp from powershell is not a problem like shown on [the scripting guy blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/02/28/use-powershell-to-configure-static-ip-and-dns-settings.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

problem solved with a really simple solution : try to ping an external host

```
if( (test-connection -quiet <external_IP_address>) -eq $false){
    #private network, allow DHCP
}
else{
    #set static ip address
}
```